# Why I am getting error "login required" when trying to contact the calendar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth

I am using Google API Calendar. Why I am getting this error message on the script below?

> There was an error contacting the calendar: login required

Current code:

```
app.post('/token', function(req, res) {
  var code = req.body.code;
  console.log(code);
  async function asyncCall() {
    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    console.log(tokens);
  }
  asyncCall();
  oauth2Client.on('tokens', tokens => {
    if (tokens.refresh_token) {
      console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
    }
    console.log(tokens.access_token);
    console.log('Now lets see');
  });
  //
  addEvents();
  function addEvents(auth) {
    var event = {
      summary: 'Google I/O 2045',
      location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
      description: "A chance to hear more about Google's 
      developer products.",
      start: {
        dateTime: '2018-10-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: '2018-10-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
      },
      recurrence: ['RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'],
      reminders: {
        useDefault: false,
        overrides: [
          { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
          { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 }
        ]
      }
    };

    //console.log(event)

    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');

    calendar.events.insert(
    {
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource: event
    },
    function(err, event) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(
            'There was an error contacting the Calendar 
             service: ' + err
          );
          return;
        }
        console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: var calendar = google.calendar('v3');

    calendar.events.insert(
      {
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource: event
      },
      function(err, event) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(
            'There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err
          );
          return;
        }
        console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
      }
    );
  }

Comment: Sorry, the indentation I messed up the indentation rules. The function is enclosed.

Comment: The error i was getting said There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: Login Required. I can't figure out the solution

Comment: Package-json: {
  "name": "testgooglecalender",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0"
  }
}

Comment: calling `asyncCall();` like that won't stop the following code from **immediately**  executing ... you're also calling `function addEvents(auth) {` like `addEvents()` ... which results in `auth` being `undefined`

Comment: so, `calendar.events.insert` will be called with undefined auth, before `oauth2Client.getToken(code)` is even finished

Comment: @SurajJagdev if you found a solution to your issue you should post it as an anwser to assist anyone who has the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. The auth should be assigned to oauth2Client in the calendar object.
2. Re-engineer your addEvents(). You do not need to define addEvents function with auth as the parameter. Also, you have to return the var events and assign it to the resource. 
   This should work:

```
app.post('/token', function(req, res) {
  var code = req.body.code;
  console.log(code);
  async function asyncCall() {
    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    console.log(tokens);
  }
  oauth2Client.on('tokens', tokens => {
    if (tokens.refresh_token) {
      console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
    }
    console.log(tokens.access_token);
    console.log('Now lets see');
  });

    function addEvents() {
    var event = {
      summary: 'Google I/O 2045',
      location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
      description: "A chance to hear more about Google's 
      developer products.",
      start: {
        dateTime: '2018-10-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: '2018-10-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
      },
      recurrence: ['RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'],
      reminders: {
        useDefault: false,
        overrides: [
          { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
          { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 }
        ]
      }
  return event;
    };

    //console.log(event)

    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');

    calendar.events.insert(
    {
        auth: oauth2Client,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource: addEvents()
    },
    function(err, event) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(
            'There was an error contacting the Calendar 
             service: ' + err
          );
          return;
        }
        console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
      }
    );
  }
});
```